# Git repository lost its remote branches?

Tags: git, version-control

I have a git repository that *has* a remote set up ("git fetch" works), but it *doesn't* have any remote branches: the ".git/refs/remotes" folder doesn't exist, and

```
git branch -r
```

returns nothing (empty list, no branches).  Yet the actual remote repository does have a branch.  If I re-clone the remote repo, I get another local repo that *does* have remote branches.

I didn't think this state was possible.  My questions:

1. How on earth did I get into this state?
2. Is there a command that can be run to put ".git/refs/remotes" back? (short of a fresh clone, which I've done already).

**Additional Information**

"git config --get remote.origin.fetch" is blank (i.e. the command produces no output)

"git remote show origin" shows

```
$ git remote show origin
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: <correct remote url here>
  Push  URL: <correct remote url here>
  HEAD branch: master
  Local ref configured for 'git push':
    master pushes to master (up to date)
```

Comment: What's the output of "git remote show origin"? [origin is remote repo name]

Comment: edited to include the output of "git remote show origin".  All looks to be in order with that command, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Some relevant context for the fetch config: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23780060/10245

Answer (score 52, accepted):

[Edit, April 2017] If you made your original clone with `--single-branch`, your `remote.origin.fetch` setting will be the problem.  If you used a `--depth` limit, that too implies `--single-branch`.  Restore the normal `remote.origin.fetch` value described below and you will get a fuller clone.

---

Normally, just running `git fetch` should restore your remote-tracking branches.

If `git fetch` is *not* restoring them, then I wonder: what goes `git config --get-all remote.origin.fetch` print?  (This assumes the remote is named `origin`; if not, substitute the actual name.)  It should be set to `+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*` (again assuming the name `origin`).  Special cases (such as fetching notes) might add more lines.

Comment: git fetch does not restore them, unfortunately.  "git config --get remote.origin.fetch" produces no output

Comment: Manually putting the value you specified into the fetch variable under the .git/config file for this repo does indeed cause "git fetch" to restore the missing remote branches.  It would still be valuable for others to know how this might happen, if anybody knows.

Comment: Odd.  `git remote add` sets up remotes with one `fetch` line, either that typical one, or the special version for mirrors (with `--mirror=fetch`).  Cloning a remote repo sets up an `origin` remote the same way.  What removed it remains a mystery as yet.

Comment: Had this issue too - I think when I cloned this repo I used `--depth=15` perhaps that's related ?

Comment: Tripped over this The only clue I can leave is that I was fetch/pushing on awful mobile internet, with --set-upstream as a default push for convenience. It makes no sense to me why that would affect anything. Thanks friends for the fix!! Screenshots at https://twitter.com/tim_abell/status/1573027018589065216

Answer (score 32):

This solved my problem

`git config --add remote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`

When I excute `vi .git/config` , I loose the fetch line:

`fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`

Comment: Might be worth quoting the value to avoid shell globbing. `git config remote.origin.fetch '+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*'`