# How to add, fetch and checkout missing remote branches?

Tags: git

I cloned my repo with the `--single-branch` option:

```
git clone -b FIRST git@<host>:repos/repo.git --single-branch
```

Now, as expected I only have this single upstream configured. Thus, the following command will not work:

```
git branch --track SECOND origin/SECOND
```

How do I add, fetch and checkout a further existing remote repository?

Comment: The question at the end of the body text doesn't match the title question _at all_, but the command you want is `git remote add new u://r/l; git fetch new`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you cloned the repository with the `--single-branch` option, it's set up to  track only this branch on the remote.

**TL;DR**: to undo the `--single-branch` entirely, undo its config setup and refetch

```
git config remote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
git fetch
```

---

In a repo set up with `--single-branch`, to `fetch` another branch once from the remote you have to fetch it explicitly.

```
git fetch origin +refs/heads/<branch-name>:refs/remotes/origin/<branch-name>
```

Alternatively you can fetch all remote branches by replacing `<branch-name>` with `*`.

Now you should be able to check out the newly fetched branch.

```
git checkout <branch-name>
```

---

### Explanation

The fetch syntax I used can roughly be described as `source:target`.
When using it you are describing the `source` of the fetch with the first path while you determine the `target` with the second path.

This means you are fetching the branch on the remote from `refs/heads/<branch>` and write the result into `refs/remotes/origin/<branch>`. Of course it's possible to write it somewhere different, for example just a local branch by using `<branch>` (also the name can be chosen as pleased).

Furthermore this explains why `git push origin :<branch>` deletes `<branch>` on the remote, because you are pushing *nothing* to the remote branch which effectively deletes it.

**NOTE** when writing `refs/heads/<branch>` `refs/heads/` is fully optional, if you just state `<branch>` git will look in `refs/heads/`. This isn't just valid for fetching but for all branch references.

Comment: This is the right answer.  Put a make-it-like-I-never-used-single-branch right up top, maybe?  the config and a bare fetch in a nice copypastable block

Comment: @jthill if you would edit the post as you proposed I will be happy to accept the changes. Because now I have to eat my lunch. ;)