# How do you merge into another branch using travis with git commands?

Tags: git, github, continuous-integration, travis-ci

I am trying to add a feature to my devstack to add auto deploy when a travis test passes on a branch called **travis**. After this test passes, I want to merge this travis branch into master branch and push to the master branch.

So far, when I push to **travis** branch, travis runs the test and everything succeeds but I am having problems with my git commands in `after_success` in my travis.yml file.

**travis.yml**

```
- "npm i -g jasmine-node"
-after_success: 
  - "git fetch"
  - "git checkout master"
  - "git merge travis"
  - "git push origin master"
 branches:
   only:
     - travis
```

This is the output on travis console:

```
error: pathspec 'master' did not match any file(s) known to git.
fatal: 'travis' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: what is the output of `git branch -a`

Comment: @codeWizard Thanks for the response, I currently don't use `git branch -a` why would I need that ?

Comment: to get the list of all your branches and to make sure that you have master localy

Comment: @codeWizard ah! I don't do that. if master doesn't exist locally, would I just need to `git pull` ?

Comment: what? i dont understand what you mean

Comment: I mean would I just need to add `git pull` in travis.yml to pull the master branch?

Comment: try this: `git fetch --all --prune && git checkout master && git pull origin travis && git push origin master `

Comment: Travis doesn't actually clone your entire repository, which is probably why this isn't working. Try pulling master and then checking it out.

Comment: @CodeWizard - with your suggestion I still get ```error: pathspec 'master' did not match any file(s) known to git.```
git branch -a (in travis) returns 
```(detached from 516eed3)
  development
  remotes/origin/development```

Answer (score 15):

## TLDR

It is not working because due to the way Travis clones repositories, the
branches don't exist locally. You need to pull them first.

In my travis build script, I call this function that allows me to pull all the
branches. Adapt it according to your need.

```bash
function create_all_branches()
{
    # Keep track of where Travis put us.
    # We are on a detached head, and we need to be able to go back to it.
    local build_head=$(git rev-parse HEAD)

    # Fetch all the remote branches. Travis clones with `--depth`, which
    # implies `--single-branch`, so we need to overwrite remote.origin.fetch to
    # do that.
    git config --replace-all remote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    git fetch
    # optionally, we can also fetch the tags
    git fetch --tags

    # create the tacking branches
    for branch in $(git branch -r|grep -v HEAD) ; do
        git checkout -qf ${branch#origin/}
    done

    # finally, go back to where we were at the beginning
    git checkout ${build_head}
}
```

## Explanation

### How Travis clones repositories

We can see in Travis logs which commands are run when it clones the repositories. It is slightly different for regular branches and for pull requests.

For a Pull Request:

```bash
# Clone the repository (note the --depth option) in ./user/repo
git clone --depth=50 https://github.com/user/repo.git user/repo

# Go the repository
cd user/repo

# Fetch the reference to the pull request 
git fetch origin +refs/pull/22/merge:

# Checkout the HEAD of the reference we just fetched. In other words,
# checkout the last commit of the PR. For details about FETCH_HEAD see
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/9237511/1836144
git checkout -qf FETCH_HEAD
```

For a regular branch (called `mybranch` in this example):

```bash
# Clone the repository (note the --depth option) in ./user/repo
# This time, we also have the --branch option
git clone --depth=50 branch=mybranch https://github.com/user/repo.git user/repo

# Go the repository
cd user/repo

# Checkout  the HEAD of the branch we just fetched
git checkout -qf 7f15290cc343249217a9b3669975705a3dc5bd44
```

In both case the `--depth` option is used when the repository is cloned, which implies `--single-branch`. Here is what `git` says about `--single-branch`:

> Clone only the history leading to the tip of a single branch, either specified by the --branch option or the primary branch remote’s HEAD points at. Further fetches into the resulting repository will only update the remote-tracking branch for the branch this option was used for the initial cloning. If the HEAD at the remote did not point at any branch when --single-branch clone was made, no remote-tracking branch is created.

In other words, only one remote branch was fetched. Worse, `git fetch` won't
even fetch the other branches.

### How to pull all the remote branches

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20338558/1836144) explains how to make `git fetch` work again:

```bash
git config --replace-all remote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Now, `git fetch` should fetch all the remote branches, but we are still not done: we want remote-tracking branches to be created. For this, we can do `git checkout` for each branch we just fetched:

```bash
for branch in $(git branch -r|grep -v HEAD) ; do
    git checkout ${branch#origin/}
done
```